# First time rasterio error

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

First of all, I am new to python and rasterio. I am trying to open a simple raster with 5 bands using the rasterio module in python.
This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
import rasterio

with rasterio.open('/Users/martinsiklar/Downloads/LC81330242015176LGN00/baikal_subset.tif') as src:
    print(src.width, src.height)
    print(src.count)
    print(src.indexes)
    print(src.dtypes)
    print(src.crs)
    print(src.transform)
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following Error and I can't really figure out what's wrong. Google didn't help either:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/martinsiklar/Martin/Python/arcpy/arcpy101", line 3, in
>   
>       with rasterio.open('/Users/martinsiklar/Downloads/LC81330242015176LGN00/baikal_subset.tif')
>   as src:   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasterio/**init**.py",
>   line 105, in open
>       from rasterio._io import RasterReader   File "**init**.pxd", line 155, in init rasterio._io (rasterio/_io.c:49668)
>
> ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
>
> > Process finished with exit code 1

When I take a look into my modules, rasterio seems to be installed properly (as far as I can tell.) The path of the .tif is also correct.  I have numpy 1.8 installed.

Comment: Looks like you have an old version of numpy. What does `python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__version__"` print out?

Comment: it prints out 1.8.0

Comment: You may need to upgrade numpy (test this out in a virtualenv, don't break your system numpy) as the numpy ABI is not forward compatible. Packages compiled against numpy 1.9 (for example) will not work with numpy 1.8 or lower. It is backwards compatible, so packages compiled against numpy 1.7 (for example) will work with numpy 1.8 or higher.  I don't use OSX, but have run into this in Windows where RasterIO wouldn't run against my numpy 1.7.1, but required numpy 1.9.

Comment: According to the [rasterio requirements](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/requirements.txt) it should work with `numpy >= 1.8.0`. What version of rasterio and GDAL are you using?

Comment: GDAL 1.11.1 and rasterio 0.31.0

Comment: @Kersten yes rasterio will work with numpy >=1.8.0 *if* the rasterio binaries (pyd) are compiled against numpy 1.8.0.  If the rasterio binaries were built against numpy 1.9x, they will only work work with numpy >= 1.9. i.e if rasterio is built against numpy 1.8, you can use numpy 1.8, 1.9, 1.10 etc. if rasterio is built against numpy 1.9, you can't use numpy 1.8, only 1.9, 1.10, etc. The error message in the Q is showing an [ABI incompatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18369312/737471)

Comment: I reinstalled all Python, GDAL, NUMPY and rasterio and now it works. Apparently there was a problem with the version compatibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is showing an [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) [incompatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18369312/737471). You need to upgrade numpy (I suggest testing this out in a virtualenv) as the numpy ABI is not [forward compatible](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5888).

This means binary extension packages (such as rasterio or pandas) that were compiled against a version of numpy (1.9 for example) will not work with an earlier version of numpy (e.g 1.8 or lower), *even if they are [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) compatible with that earlier version*.

While rasterio is API compatible with numpy >=1.8, it will only work with numpy 1.8 if the rasterio binaries (pyd) are compiled against numpy 1.8.  If the rasterio binaries were built against numpy 1.9x, they will only work with numpy >= 1.9.

i.e if rasterio is built against numpy 1.8, you can use rasterio with numpy 1.8, 1.9, 1.10 etc. However, if rasterio is built against numpy 1.9, you can't use numpy 1.8, only 1.9, 1.10, etc.